# How to update view via model in JavaFX MVC?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, fxml

I have FXML application with model, view and controller. My view is in .fxml file and I have Text there like this

```
<Text fx:id="position" text="None" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
   <font>
      <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
   </font>
</Text>
```

My Controller look like this

```
public class Controller{

   @FXML
   private Text position;

   public void updatePosition(String text){
      position.setText(text);
   }
}
```

In my Model, there I have String variable, which is changing throughout all my project. Model look like this

```
public class Model {

   public String position = "None";

   public  String getPosition() {
      return tactic;
   }

   public void setPosition(String position) {
      this.position = position;
   }
}
```

There are another classes in my project, which call setPositon method and update variable position. Is there a way how to change Text in my view, when someone change position variable in Model class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to observe the model. The easiest way to do this in JavaFX is to use [JavaFX properties](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) to represent the data.

```
public class Model {

    private final StringProperty position = new SimpleStringProperty("None");

    public StringProperty positionProperty() {
        return position ;
    }

    public final String getPosition() {
        return positionProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setPosition(String position) {
        positionProperty().set(position);
    }
}
```

Now you can simply bind the text's `textProperty()` to the model's `positionProperty()`, and if the model's position is changed, the text will automatically update:

```
public class Controller{

   @FXML
   private Text position;

   private Model model ;

   public void initialize() {
       position.textProperty().bind(model.positionProperty());
   }

   // ...
}
```

The only tricky part now is to make sure the controller has a reference to the correct model instance. The best way to do this is to provide a constructor for the controller taking a model:

```
public class Controller {

   @FXML
   private Text position;

   private final Model model ;

   public Controller(Model model) {
       this.model = model ;
   }

   public void initialize() {
       position.textProperty().bind(model.positionProperty());
   }

   // ...
}
```

The problem now is that the default mechanism for creating controllers via the `FXMLLoader` relies on a zero-argument constructor, so it won't work. So you need to remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the FXML file and set the controller "by hand":

```
Model model = new Model(); // or just reference to existing model...

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("View.fxml"));
loader.setController(new Controller(model));
Parent root = loader.load();
// ...

model.setPosition("Left"); // will update text in view
```

See [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml) for more ways to pass the model (or other data) to the controller.

Also see the related question [Applying MVC With JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx/32343342#32343342)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It works well. One more thing - when I create instance of Model like this `Model model = new Model();` I have to use this instance in another class, so it has to be static, because I canot make instanse of class which extends Application. It there a way how to not use static instance of model ?

Comment: @M.Barabas If you create it in, for example, the `start()` method, you should be able to pass it to any controller (or other class) that needs it, since the `start()` method is the entry point for the entire application. That can sometimes get a bit complex, in which case I would recommend using a dependency injection framework (such as Guice, Weld, or Spring). You might also be interested in [afterburner.fx](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/) (essentially a JavaFX-specific DI framework).